# Node.js "require" vs just <script src="dependency.js"> earlier in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, import, require

I've noticed that when we have a javascript file, let's call it example1.js, that used jquery, all we need to do is include jquery before we use example1.js.

i.e)

```
<script link="jquery"><\script>
<script link="example1.js"><\script>
```

This confuses me because i'm learning about "require" in node. And i'm aware that using require on jquery is not something that is done whatsoever. But then why do we include other js dependencies, and then import jquery through style tags? Is it the same thing? Or are these two things different? Thanks

Comment: Different things.  Nodejs uses a module system where NO variables are global by default.  In the browser, all top level variables/functions are global by default.  This led many to use a browser structure where you load a script and it defines a bunch of globals that any scripts coming after it can then use.  That's not at all how nodejs works.  If you want to use a function/value from a module in nodejs, you HAVE to `import` or `require()` that module to get access to it.

Comment: And, FYI, I think you mean `<script src="/example1.js"></script>`, not `<style ...></style>`.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I'm a bit confused, though, because I used the node package manager to install two packages. Chessboardjs and chessjs. And i'm noticing that I'm able to use both of these files without any explicit require statement in my javascript files because I would link them earlier in my main html file. Therefore, can't I assume that this has provided me the same functionality as what "require" would have done?

Comment: I will try one more time.  `require()` is for code that runs in nodejs.  `<script>` tags are for use in an HTML page that runs in the browser.  These are two completely different environments.  Do not attempt to compare how they both work as they are just different.  If you don't understand how their Javascript environments are different, then please go read about the client/server concept for HTML pages and Javascript as it's a pretty fundamental concept here that helps you understand where code runs and in what environment it's running.

Comment: Thank you for the help and pointing me to a resource. Am still learning. Cheers.